# Initiate Spotify track playback at a given start time using the iOS Spotify SDK?

Tags: ios, spotify

We're using the iOS Spotify sdk to play Spotify tracks via `SPTAudioStreamingController`.  I'm playing a track via `playURIs:fromIndex:callback` but the goal is to play it back starting from a given time offset (vs the start of the track).

I've tried passing a callback to `playURIs:fromIndex:callback` that calls `seekToOffset:callback` to the desired time index but that fails or is otherwise ignored (presumably because the Spotify player internals aren't yet set up in a state to perform the seek).

I would even consider initiating a seek via `dispatch_get_main_queue()` with a delay, but that makes me (a) want to take a shower and (b) has the gross side effect of hearing the first second or two of audio before the seek is executed.  Yikes!

If there's any devs who know the internals that could hit tip a quality way to do this, that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
- (void)playURIs:(NSArray *)uris withOptions:(SPTPlayOptions *)options callback:(SPTErrorableOperationCallback)block
```

If you read up on SPTPlayOptions, one of them is startTime which you can configure in seconds.